# How to get a rolling data set by week with sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dataset

I had a sql query I would run that would get a rolling sum (or moving window) data set. I would run this query for every 7 days, increase the interval number by 7 (28 in example below) until I reached the start of the data. It would give me the data split by week so I can loop through it on the view to create a weekly graph.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `row_date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 28 DAY)
  AND `row_date` <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 28 DAY)
```

This is of course very slow once you have several weeks worth of data. I wanted to replace it with a single query. I came up with this.

```
  SELECT *
  CONCAT(YEAR(row_date), '/', WEEK(row_date)) as week_date
  FROM `table`
  GROUP BY week_date
  ORDER BY row_date DESC
```

It appeared mostly accurate, except I noticed the current week and the last week of 2015 was much lower than usual. That's because this query gets a week starting on Sunday (or Monday?) meaning that it resets weekly.

Here's a data set of employees that you can use to demonstrate the behavior.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id          INT             NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    row_date    DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES
(1,'Bezalel','Simmel','2016-12-25'),
(2,'Bezalel','Simmel','2016-12-31'),
(3,'Bezalel','Simmel','2017-01-01'),
(4,'Bezalel','Simmel','2017-01-05')
```

This data will return the last 3 rows on the same data point on the old query (last 7 days) assuming you run it today 2017-01-06, but only the last 2 rows on the same data point on the new query (Sunday to Saturday).

For more information on what I mean by rolling or moving window, see this English stack exchange link.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362791/word-for-graph-that-counts-backwards-vs-graph-that-counts-forwards

How can I write a query in MySQL that will bring me rolling data, where the last data point is the last 7 days of data, the previous point is the previous 7 days, and so on?

Comment: Given your query, why can't you just do `select * from `order`?  What is a "rolling data set"?

Comment: Returns the data grouped by week. This way I can graph it weekly. I'll try to clarify on the question.

Comment: @Strawberry good point. I can provide the exact data set or structure, but I edited my answer to show how to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @Strawberry I've updated the question with a real data set that will work to demonstrate the question.

Comment: Isn't that just the full dataset from http://sink.agiletoolkit.org/employees?  May I suggest providing an example dataset that is significantly smaller than 17MB along with some sample SELECT queries / datasets.  Not entirely sure what else you expect from start/end weeks, as they typically do not contain 7 days and so they will have smaller sums.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net Correct. I'll write up an absolute minimum data set and edit it into my question. Still not sure the point of the problem is getting across. Intended behavior is if today is Tuesday, I want the data for the last 7 days, not from Sunday to Tuesday.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net, I've updated with the minimum data to replicate and instructions. Is the question clear now?

Comment: Your dataset has duplicate entries for PK

Comment: @Simonatmso.net sorry about that, fixed

Comment: @Strawberry My old query would get data 7 days at a time, so if you run the query on a Friday, data points from Saturday would be included in the most recent week data point. New query treats weeks strictly as Sunday to Saturday, so Saturday data point would be last week. My sample data demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: I've tried this out and I don't see the issue - see this sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55082/1

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what's so difficult about providing a sample result set.

Comment: @Strawberry I have already provided sample create table and insert table and specified the intended results. I'll try to edit to clarify.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net that seems to work, but you've changed the query quite a bit from mine. Perhaps that's the query I need to be using? I'm a little confused why you're query doesn't include the 5th in it's results.

Comment: I have changed it again since you probably posted that, check again.  I changed the query because you were selecting a date from a grouped field which will return 1 value from a group.  By using MIN/MAX I am being clear that I am looking for the upper and lower bounds based on the data in the dataset.  Are you looking to get the data grouped up in periods of 7 days back from today, instead of the current which is grouping on calendar weeks?

Comment: @Simonatmso.net ah, see, I want the data point of 2016-12-31 included in the current week. Just seeing you next comment now. Exactly!! I want 7 days back from today, and so on, a rolling window or moving window data set. That is how my old query worked and I'm trying to keep that behavior.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net if you can edit my question to be more clear to others, please do, because it seems I've done a very poor job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had to interpret your question a lot so this answer might be unsuitable.  It sounds like you are trying to get a graph showing data historically grouped into 7-day periods.  Your current attempt does this by grouping on calendar week instead of by 7-day period leading to inconsistent size of periods.

So using a modification of your dataset on sql fiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90f1f2 ) I have come up with this

```
  SELECT 
    -- Figure out how many periods of 7 days ago this record applies to
    FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE , row_date ) / 7 ) AS weeks_ago,
    -- Count the number of ids in this group
    COUNT( DISTINCT id ) AS number_in_week,
    -- Because this is grouped, make sure to have some consistency on what we select instead of leaving it to chance
    MIN( row_date ) AS min_date_in_week_in_dataset 
  FROM `sample_data`
  -- Groups by weeks ago because that's what you are interested in
  GROUP BY weeks_ago
  ORDER BY 
    min_date_in_week_in_dataset DESC;
```

Comment: Query is giving me strange results. Is `weeks_ago` suppose to return fractions?

Comment: Ah, using floor, as in  `floor(DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE , order_date ) / 7) AS weeks_ago` causes the exact behavior I'm expecting. Edit this into your question if you agree and I'll gladly accept. You guys have been very patient.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to update my answer with the query from my sqlfiddle.  For future reference, using SQL fiddle to provide reproduction criteria, along with a text-representation of what you would like the data to look like, would probably be fare easier than trying to describe it!